# Mvc5 database SQL, VS 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I need your help, I am doing Mvc project in VS 2013 with SQL database, I have created database first and then I complete my project, but now working on project I change data type of one column, and the run project, it gives this kind of error.

Comment: your question needs to be improved. give your code and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

By "database first", I'm assuming you mean your using EDMX. The EDMX is a snapshot of your database at the moment is was generated. If you change something in your database, you have to regenerate the EDMX.

Comment: it means i should delete my previous edmx and regenerate it?

Comment: Exactly. Every time you make a change. It won't update for you automatically.

Comment: Or use the `Update model from database` feature (instead of constantly deleting + recreating the whole EDMX)